# nsmutabledictionnary with nsmutablestring forkey

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a nsmutabledictionnary, and when I use setObject:forKey: with a nsstring key it works when I try objectForKey, but if I put a nsmutablestring in the key argument of the SetObject:forKey: method, it's not work when I call objectForKey, it return the last object in the dictionnary...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should know that NSDictionary (and NSMutableDictionary) copies the key before adding it - thus, if you use a NSMutableString as a key, then modify that same string, the key in the database will still have the old value. This is done for a reason - the key in a NSDictionary should always be static, since it's actually the hash of it that's used for retrieving the associated value.

Comment: So what I can do, I try  
NSString *myString =[[NSString alloc] initWithString: [@"fr_" stringByAppendingString: myMutableString]];

and put myString in the key argument but this not work...

Comment: ok it's works! thanx for the great explication in your answer!

Comment: The corresponding CFDictionary functions do not copy keys. I use this so I don't need to wrap (e.g.) NSURLConnections to use them as keys. Only do this on objects which don't override `-(NSUInteger)hash`.

Comment: Shit will still hit the fan if you change the object after you've added it as key ;)

Answer (score 0):

If a normal string works, but the mutable one doesn't, then why don't you just add another line of code and convert it to a normal string?

`NSString *keyValue = mutableStringVariable;`

Comment: if you do this, your string KeyValue just point on the mutableStringVariable object, so you have the same object at the end